# Taskbar is missing following Windows updates in Windows 11

Tags: windows, taskbar, windows-11-v22h2

I just applied Windows updates and shut down. Two days later when I started up, my taskbar is completely missing. I am able to run desktop icons but start menu key doesn't bring up start menu, taskbar is nowhere to be found. The updates that were applied were driver updates.

The updates were all Intel packages. I don't have exact details because I can't open the updates panel without a run dialog or a start menu. but that's my situation.

I am on a Dell Optiplex 5540 laptop with an i5-13x processor (again, that's what i recall, can't pull up exact spec), 16G RAM, 256GB SSD.

Plenty of drive space, running OneDrive (and also SharePoint through it), MS Teams for Work, Sophos EP, and 3cx desktop app (all startup apps I recall).

Comment: Did you restart again?  Shut down, start up and check.  Run DISM / SFC .........  (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: If you boot into Safe Mode does the behavior change?

Comment: Do not edit your header title to say “[Solved](https://superuser.com/posts/1820249/revisions).” You can check off an answer that solved your problem even with no rep. Just click the check to the left of the answer. If there is a delay between when you can check off an answer because you are new user, then just wait for the period to end and then check it off. You can also upvote the answer as well. Same rules apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over the last two years, MS has been trying to fix various issues with the Windows 11 Taskbar, as described in this [2021 article](https://www.windowslatest.com/2021/12/28/microsoft-is-trying-to-fix-windows-11-taskbar-issues/), and [this from 2022](https://www.xda-developers.com/windows-11-beta-channel-builds-fix-taskbar/) . Perhaps a *further* update needs to be completed on your PC to fix the issue.

To run Update again, without needing the Taskbar,

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>,
- Type `ms-settings:windowsupdate`,
- And press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If that does not resolve the issue, [download the ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11) using the Windows 11 Installation Media Creation Tool from Microsoft and reinstall, keeping files.

Comment: the additional update did bring it back, before I even ran the update check, oddly enough.  Went ahead and ran it anyway.  I appreciate the suggestion!  From everyone.  Thanks.  

It's so odd that restarts and safe boots did not, but just opening Windows update did.  It's like I scared it with the threat of an update check... :-D

Comment: Not sure how to mark as solved or mark an answer, my rep isn't high enough, but anyway.  I'll just edit my header title.

Comment: @user1869694 Do not edit your header title to say “[Solved](https://superuser.com/posts/1820249/revisions).” You can check off an answer that solved your problem even with no rep. Just click the check to the left of the answer. If there is a delay between when you can check off an answer because you are new user, then just wait for the period to end and then check it off. You can also upvote the answer as well. Same rules apply.

Comment: Done for answer mark, still no good for upvoting though... error says my rep is not high enough.  Thanks.  Sorry about breaking etiquette.